# I got error when I click in Like button in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I got error when I click in like button in Django
**Video matching query does not exist.**

**the traceback**

```
video_obj = Video.objects.get(id=video_id)
```

I follow tutorial in youtube I got error
when I click in like button the error appear
how I can solve this problem

This my model for video

```
class Video(models.Model):
author = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
video = models.FileField(upload_to='post-videos', validators=[validate_file_extension])
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
liked = models.ManyToManyField(Account, blank=True, related_name='likes')
```

my view

```
def like_unlike_videos(request):
user = request.user
if request.method == 'POST':
    video_id = request.POST.get('video_id')
    video_obj = Video.objects.get(id=video_id)
    account = Account.objects.get(username=user)

    if account in video_obj.liked.all():
        video_obj.liked.remove(account)
    else:
        video_obj.liked.add(account)

    like, created = Like.objects.get_or_create(username=account, video_id=video_id)

    if not created:
        if like.value == 'Like':
            like.value = 'Unlike'
        else:
            like.value = 'Like'

    else:
        like.value = 'Like'

        video_obj.save()
        like.save()

    data = {

    }
    data = {
        'value': like.value,
        'likes': video_obj.liked.all()
    }
return render(request ,'video/the_video.html', data)
```

my template

```
  <form action="{% url 'video:like-video-view' %}" method="POST" class="like-form" id='{{video.id}}'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value={{video.id}}>  
        <button type="submit" class="ui button like-btn{{video.id}}">
            {% if account not in video.liked.all %}
               Like
            {% else %}
               Unlike
            {% endif %}
        </button>
          <div class="ui grid">
              <div class="column">
                 <div class="like-count{{video.id}}"> {{video.num_likes}} </div>
              </div>
              <div class="column">
                 likes
            </div>
          </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of your parameter is `post_id`, but should be `video_id`:

```
<input type="hidden" name="video_id" value="{{video.id}}">
```

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

Comment: Thank you I have got another problem `Cannot resolve keyword 'username' into field. Choices are: created, id, updated, user, user_id, value, video, video_id
`

Comment: the traceback `like, created = Like.objects.get_or_create(author=account, video_id=video_id) `

Comment: `Field 'id' expected a number but got ''.`

Comment: What is `{{ video.id }}` in the template? Are you sure that this renders a primary key? Perhaps `video` is *not* in the context?

Comment: Actually I don't sure